# Calling Ruby class methods with pluralized model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.by_title_and_description(title, description)
    #logic for method redacted
  end

end
```

And in order to call that method it's:

```
Recipe.by_title_and_description(title, description)
```

However I was wondering if there is a way to do this because my method returns multiple instances.

```
Recipes.by_title_and_description(title, description)
```

As it seems more intuitive. 
Not a big deal, but I was just curious.

Comment: Yes, it is seem semantically intuitive, but clashes with Rails conventions. So in the interest of using other Rails libraries, I would not pursue it.

Answer (score 3):

If you really dare to use this style of Rails programming, you could write

```
Recipes = Recipe
```

which defines another constant name for the Recipe class.

Answer (score 1):

It goes against Rails models naming convention.
The common case of using finder methods is to pluralize (or not) variable name.
Something like this.

```
@recipes = Recipe.mutliple_by_title_and_description(title, description) # return multiple instances
@recipe = Recipe.by_title_and_description(title, description) # return one instance
```

---

I don't like this programming style but you can inherit class to do it.

```
class Recipes
  def self.by_title_and_description(title, description)
    # logic to return multiple instances 
  end
end

class Recipe < Recipes
  def self.by_title_and_description(title, description)
    super.first # this will return first instance from parent method
  end
end
```

As for me it makes code less readable and more "smelly".

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be:

```
class Recipes < Recipe
end
Recipes.by_title_and_description(title, description)
```

That makes it useless.

A few more ways:

```
define_method("Recipes") do
  Recipe
end

instance_eval('self.Recipes.by_title_and_description("title", "description")')
send("Recipes").by_title_and_description("title", "description")
```

Of course not going to use any of these, but I found all of this quite interesting.